# Redirect to a controller's action from another controller while action name is same in both controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two controller Controller1 and Controller2.
I am redirecting to a action name Action1 of controller Controller1 from the controller Controller2 while in controller Controller2 there is a action names Action1.
So when I am using

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Action1", "Controller1", new { id = "btnCancel", @class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block FLarge " })
```

It redirects to the the action Action1 of Controller2 .

Please can you help me out on this

Comment: HAve you cleared the cache? Also can you please give the url formed?

Comment: It very much should not be doing this.  What steps have you taken to confirm that this is the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: one more thing if you wont have text for action link then how are you going to click that?

Comment: How would you click on an empty string?!

Comment: @TusharGupta yes i have cleared the cashe but the problem is still persisiting and i have given the text for the action link

Comment: can you post the actual code you're using?

Comment: Then please the code you wrote...Its hard to find the difference

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Action1", "Controller1", new { id = "btnCancel", @class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block FLarge " })   this was the code of view which is bind with the Controller2 in which there was a action named Action1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, posting that actual code you were using helps.  You are actually using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
   this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
   string linkText,
   string actionName,
   Object routeValues,
   Object htmlAttributes
)
```

you want [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
   this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
   string linkText,
   string actionName,
   string controllerName,
   Object routeValues,
   Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Essentially, add an empty object **before** your `htmlAttributes`.  You'll notice from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx) there is no overload for `string, string, string, object`.  You have to be careful with those `@Html` overloads, it's very easy to grab the wrong one without a compiler error.

In the end, you want:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Action1", "Controller1", null, new { id = "btnCancel", @class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block FLarge " })
```